# Why are my NEF files damaged?

Tags: troubleshooting, photoshop-cs5, raw, data-corruption, adobe-bridge

Can anyone help? 
After buying a Nikon D3100, I discovered that NEF files were not compatible with CS3, so at great expense, I bought CS5. Now... my raw NEF files are almost always corrupt when viewed in Adobe Bridge, Camera Raw or Photoshop.

They're nearly always OK when viewed in Nikon ViewNX 2

A classic example with metadata is here http://www.first-hit.co.uk/corrupt_nef/

Comment: Have you tried updating Adobe Camera Raw?

Comment: +1 to Stan, sounds like a bug in your RAW converter rather than the files themselves. To make sure, download trial versions of e.g. Bibble and DXo and see for yourself that those can read the files correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Try converting the files from NEF to DNG with Adobe DNG Converter, and see if CS5 can open the DNG file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start conducting tests to see if I get the same results with a different card, as well as ensuring the underlying file system is correct (full format of the card), as well as trying the same card on a different machine, trying a different reader, and checking with a local photography club that someone else with the same camera model can produce something your machine could read.

(I was bit by a USB cable that had gone bad -- while I didn't think that could matter, substitution and testing proved it. It'd work just long enough to get some data over, and then corrupt things enough to even dismount.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very VERY long shot. But way back when, I remember having problems opening files (they were jpegs) in ImageReady. I ended up working out that it was because they had an odd number of bytes.

I can't remember now exactly where I was getting these odd-byte-numbered files from, nor how I went about padding them out, but my recollection is that it did fix the problem.

Just a thought...